# Select Substring of Column in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, substring, sequelize.js

I am working with sequelize. I want to select a substring in my where clause like this in SQL SUBSTRING(description_column, 1, 200). I am selecting by page, pagesize and limiting description_column to length of 200. I don't know if I can achieve it with raw query since I want pagination which findAll and FindAndCountAll offers which I want to use. How can I achieve this? The only substring I find in sequelize works this way

[Op.substring]: 'hat' // LIKE '%hat%'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Sequelize.literal()` to use the Standard SQL functions:

```
const options = {
  attributes: [
    'id',
    sequelize.literal('SUBSTRING(description_column, 1, 200) as description_column')
  ]
}
MyTable.find(options).success(success);
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked. Here is how I used it. The caller sends the description length param. I saw another solution here also. [link](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/5265)

`[Sequelize.literal(`SUBSTRING(description, 1, ${descriptionLength})`), 'description']`